# fastai cnn_learner not advancing

Tags: python, python-3.9, fast-ai

I am trying to make an object detection from fastai library with 130 pic of the object that i want to detect but the learner is not learning or not advancing like the [tutorial](https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.vision.html)

code:

```
def label_func(x): return x.parent.name

path = Path("F:/Visual Code/Python/shitshow/")
fnames = get_image_files(path/'dates')
#print(fnames)
torch.cuda.set_device('cuda:0')
print(f"Total Images:{len(fnames)}")
dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_path_func(path, fnames, label_func, bs=64, num_workers=0,item_tfms=Resize(400))
learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet18, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fine_tune(2)
```

output:

```
Total Images:125
epoch     train_loss  valid_loss  error_rate  time
0         0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    00:04
```

- python 3.9
- fastai 2.5.3
- fastcore 1.3.27

Comment: Please see [ask]. There is no way to answer this question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.